# How to detect that ad blocker is blocking ads in my app?

Tags: android, admob, adblock

I am showing AdMob ads in my native android app. I want to detect in my app that if user is using any ad blocker to block ads in my app. If user is using ad blocker then I want to show pop up in app and ask him to turn off ad blocker while using the app.

Is there a way to detect that ads are being blocked? Please help.